# Change initial style value with animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an element

```
<form class="fade-in-form">...</form>
```

with an animation

```
.fade-in-login-form{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; !important;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; !important;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1; !important;
    }
}
```

and I want the element to be invisible at first, but then fading in.
The problem is that the `form` is invisible at first (`opacity: 0;`), then fades in, but after the animation flashes to be invisible again! Why doesn't the animation overwrite the initial value of `opacity: 0;` with `opacity: 1;`? And how can I achieve what I want?
If the solution requires Javascript: I prefer AngularJS over jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

An animation by default only applies as long as it is running. When it ends running, it no longer applies

If you want to change this behaviour, you need to use the animation-fill-mode property

In your case, the value is forwards

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

(With prefixes if needed)

Comment: And you can put all in the shorthand animation property as in :  
`animation: fadein 2s 3s forwards`

Answer (score 0):

First, syntax-wise, I think you should not have a semi-colon between your values and !important (not a good one to use, by the way) :

```
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s !important;
```

Second, I guess the styles are not applied because your elements are not loaded ; if you set display to block on the form and set it back to block after page content is loaded with javascript (see code below), does it work better ?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
{
     document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
});
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/sodawillow/pen/PwbNLa)

Answer (score 0):

Just leave off the `opacity: 0;` in your first selector:

```
.fade-in-form {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s 3s; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
          animation: fadein 2s 3s; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

As @sodawillow mentioned try never ever to use `!important` but if you really have to use it like this: `property-name: property-value !important;`

Comment: this does not work. It might have to do with the fact that I have Angular directives in my `form`

Comment: @Clawish Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogYxKw?editors=110) which shows that this works with a really simple `form`. Provide a stripped down CodePen with your code, so we have a change to analyse further.